# Is there a workaround for z-index of child of position:fixed not working in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Chrome handles z-indexes below a position:fixed element differently than Firefox or Safari. -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/a6qL8bhL/)

From Adam Spiers in another answer here, I´ve learned that it´s due to [on mobile WebKit and Chrome 22+, `position: fixed` always creates a new stacking context, even when `z-index` is `auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Is there a workaround for this? Any way to prevent chrome from creating a  new stacking context? Replacing the position: fixed is hardly an option as it´s for fixing a website tutorial software that highlights parts of the page with z-index.

Comment: Helpful read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Answer (score 0):

If your set the z-index of the pink div to 0, like this:

```
.div1 {
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
height: 100px;
background-color: pink;
}
```

And the z-index of your green div to 1 it will be displayed right in chrome and firefox.

Comment: Thanks, that does fix the example code. Unfortunately, it doesn´t attack the problem itself... :(

Comment: it's difficult to help with these few information. Describe your problem, which can't get fixed with z-index:0 of your base-element and every element above +1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I just opened a [pull request](https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/pull/335) that will allow you to control where the backdrop is injected into the page. This will not prevent Chrome from creating a new stacking context, but it would at least allow you to place the backdrop into the same stacking context as the step element. If accepted this might be able to resolve your problem.